# How to keep specific word groups on separate lines in a Jetpack Compose text widget?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm working on a UI project using Jetpack Compose, and I have a requirement for a text widget. I need to ensure that specific words stay together in separate lines. For example, if the text is "Some text example for stackoverflow question," and the word 'question' appears in the second line, I want the word 'stackoverflow' to also be in the second line.

Desired output:

```
Some text example for
stackoverflow question
```

I'm looking for guidance, code examples, or best practices on how to implement this behavior in Jetpack Compose. Any suggestions on how to achieve this requirement would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you specify the full requirements for words being on the same line?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: for example, you said that you want stackoverflow and question to be on the same line.  Does that mean you want all adjectives / adverbs preceding a certain noun / verb on the same line as that noun / verb?

Comment: Not really. I meant that if there is not enough space to place text in one row and the second is required, I don't want only one word in the second line. I want min 2 words to be in the new row

Answer (score 0):

here is a function that should solve this issue:

```kotlin
fun parseText(str: String, len: Int) {
    var lineChars = 0 //total chars in a line
    val out = ArrayList<String>() //our intermediate result
    val wordArray = str.split(Regex("\\s")) //split the string on whitespace
    for(word in wordArray) {
        out.add(word)
        lineChars += (word.length + 1) //count the word's chars (plus a space) to lineChars
        if((len until len + 10).contains(lineChars)) { //if we've reached our desired line length
            out.add("\n") //add a newline
            lineChars = 0 //reset the char count for a new line
        }
    }
    val indexOfBreak = wordArray.lastIndexOf("\n") 
    if(indexOfBreak > out.size - 3 && longString.length > len) { //if a newline is one of the last two elements
        out[indexOfBreak] = out[indexOfBreak - 1] //swap the newline and the element before it
        out[indexOfBreak - 1] = "\n"
    }
    return out.joinToString(" ").split("\n ").joinToString("\n") //return the formatted string
```